# Celery + Python: Queue time consuming tasks within another task

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I want to query an api (which is time consuming) with lots of items (~100) but not all at once. Instead I want a little delay between the queries.

What I currently have is a task that gets executed asynchronously and iterates over the queries and after each iteration waits some time:

```
@shared_task
def query_api_multiple(values):
    delay_between_queries = 1

    query_results = []

    for value in values:
        time.sleep(delay_between_queries)

        response = query_api(value)
        if response['result']:
            query_results.append(response)

    return query_results
```

My question is, when multiple of those requests come in, will the second request gets executed after the first is finished or while the first is still running? And when they are not getting executed at the same time, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You should use ETA – Scheduling a task for later, for doing that asynchronously using ETA(estimated time of arrival)  like: later = now + timedelta(hours=1)
access_awful_system.apply_async((object_id), eta=later)  [reference](https://fernandofreitasalves.com/using-celery-with-multiple-queues-retries-and-scheduled-tasks/) ETA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you create multiple tasks then they may run at the same time.

You can rate limit on a task type basis with celery if you want to limit the number of tasks that run per period of time. Alternatively, you could implement a rate limiting pattern using something like redis, combined with celery retries,  if you need more flexibility than what celery provides OOtB.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `time.sleep` but rate limit your task instead:

> [`Task.rate_limit`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit)
>
> Set the rate limit for this task type (limits the
>   number of tasks that can be run in a given time frame).
>
> The rate limits can be specified in seconds, minutes or hours by
>   appending “/s”, “/m” or “/h” to the value. Tasks will be evenly
>   distributed over the specified time frame.
>
> Example: “100/m” (hundred tasks a minute). This will enforce a minimum
>   delay of 600ms between starting two tasks on the same worker instance.

So if you want to limit it to 1 query per second, try this:

```
@shared_task(rate_limit='1/s')
def query_api_multiple(values):
    ...
```

Comment: This rate limit only applies per worker, either they are asking you to add this task to a queue and then have only 1 worker process that queue or not add a rate limit at all, is there a better way of handling this where all workers would adhere to the rate limit